# Array Formula For Displays The Total Values ​in a Data Set (COUNTA)

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a Google sheet with fixed number of columns and dynamic rows.
I like to use countA to count fields with a value (non-blank) in the current row.
I try to modification Formula from my previous answered question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74189964/arrayformula-for-join-a-range-column)
[image]

To concatenate Data every added New Row Data, I use Formula in Cell G1 :

={"CONCATENATE DATA"; INDEX(TRIM(FLATTEN(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IF(B2:F="";;B2:F&","));;9^9))))}

I think, I can make modification formula from it, to Count Values (COUNTA Formula) in Column H.
After some trial, I am failed.

I want the formula can calculate with the result as in the column I.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try:

```
=byrow(B2:F;lambda(z;if(counta(z)=0;;counta(z))))
```

Comment: Just in case you can also try this one for **Column G** `=byrow(B2:F;lambda(z;if(counta(z)=0;;textjoin(", ";1;z))))`

Comment: Thanks @rockinfreakshow , it's work  for Column G.
This formula new for Me.
Although I don't understand yet, I will try to learn this alternative formula. Thanks again.